# How change class component of switch to functional component in react native expo

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, expo

I have class component that work for switch

```
 state = {
   
    showMen: this.props.user.showMen,
    showWomen: this.props.user.showWomen,
  }


  updateUser = (key, value) => {
    const {uid} = this.props.user
    firebase.database().ref('Users').child(uid)
      .update({[key]:value})
  }

  render() {
   
    const { showMen, showWomen} = this.state
        <View style={styles.switch}>
          <Text>Show Men</Text>
          <Switch
            value={showMen}
            onValueChange={val => {
              this.setState({showMen:val})
              this.updateUser('showMen', val)
            }}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.switch}>
          <Text>Show Women</Text>
          <Switch
            value={showWomen}
            onValueChange={val => {
              this.setState({showWomen:val})
              this.updateUser('showWomen', val)
            }}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
```

I want to convert to Hook component and want insert data in to firestore of existing users data
may be setDoc() should use
but I have problem in changing this class to hook
Can someone help me
How can change this codes to hook components and insert to firestore
thanks you

Comment: did you try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed it; but I didn't quietly understand what is setDoc() doing?

if you could provide more info, It would be great.

```
const Comp = ({ user }) => {
  const [showMen, setShowMen] = useState(user.showMen);
  const [showWomen, setShowWomen] = useState(user.showWomen);

  const updateUser = (key, value) => {
    const { uid } = user;
    firebase
      .database()
      .ref("Users")
      .child(uid)
      .update({ [key]: value });
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <View style={styles.switch}>
        <Text>Show Men</Text>
        <Switch
          value={showMen}
          onValueChange={(val) => {
            setShowMen(val);
            updateUser("showMen", val);
          }}
        />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.switch}>
        <Text>Show Women</Text>
        <Switch
          value={showWomen}
          onValueChange={(val) => {
            setShowWomen(val);
            updateUser("showWomen", val);
          }}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: hello bro, setDoc() is for firestore data inserting. if data insert into firestore not into realtime database may be like this  ```setDoc(doc(db,'users',user.uid), { [key]: value }```.thanks for your help bro .I will accept this answer